# Parametrizing an ORM based SqlAlchemy query

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am new to SqlAlchemy and trying to figure out the best way to go about what I am attempting to configure.

I am migrating a Flask/Postgresql webapp from a basic psycopg2 driver to a SqlALchemy ORM based one, and I have a basic ORM related class setup.

Say I have a base level object called an `event`.

I have multiple `users` associated to this `event`.

`Event` has attributes `created_date`, `_key`, `description`.

Now, what I would like to achieve, is that I query for something in `event`, and also automatically return additional calculated attributes. I understand how to create a calculated attribute based on the three columns that I listed (`created_date`, `_key`, `description`), but I have an additional requirement - different users will have different calculated values. So I want to have a user specific query, where I can pass the user's ID into the `@property` so I can then calculate the appropriate values.

So putting it together, the code would look like:

```
class Event(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'activity'
        _key = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        created_date = Column(String)
        description = Column(String)

        @property
        def calculated_attribute(self):
            # Do some lookups here based on user_id
            calculated_attr = "ResultOfLogic"
            return calculated_attr
```

and then perform something like this:

as `user_id = 1`

```
    with session_scope as session:
       session.query(Event).all()
```

and receive data similar to this:

```
   description: "Description"
   created_date: "1/7/2020"
   calculated_attr: "Result calculated for user 1"
```

or for `user_id=2`:

```
   description: "Description"
   created_date: "1/7/2020"
   calculated_attr: "Something totally different"
```

I tried adding self.user_id in an init constructor in Event, but it seems that we are working with `entities` and not instances of classes with sqlalchemy. Is what I am attempting to do even possible, or will I have to do some manual work to create these objects after my query? I would like to be able to use sql to also sort on these properties, which was one of the reasons I was trying to calculate these results when I execute the query.

Comment: Maybe you can use this https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html.

Comment: If you want your logic both in Python and SQL level, you can use ```hybrid_property```. If you want only in Python, use ```column_property```

Comment: Andrex - I am looking at ```Query-time SQL expressions as mapped attributes``` - this may work, I am going to give that a try and update if it does!
and right, in this case I may just want column_property.

Answer (score 0):

For those who make their way here looking for an answer:

Turns out, you can do something like this:

```
class Event(Base):
        user_id = None
        __tablename__ = 'activity'
        _key = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        created_date = Column(String)
        description = Column(String)

        @property
        def calculated_attribute(self):
            # Use user_id in here like self.
            return self.user_id + "Hi!"
```

Than your query would look like:

```
    with session_scope as session:
           Event.user_id = "Your_User_Id"
           session.query(Event).all()
```